# What's the English cognate with German "Stick" and Dutch "stik"?

Tags: etymology, translation, germanic-languages

Is there an English cognate with German *Stick* (as in *Stickstoff*) and Dutch *stik* (as in *stikstof*)?

What's the absolutely literal calque of *Stickstoff/stikstof* meaning nitrogen?

Comment: It's probably worth adding here that the *Stick-* part comes from *ersticken,* "to smother, suffocate".

Comment: Are you looking for a combining form that indicates *nitrogen* or something that implies *suffocation* per @AndrewLeach? If the former, consider ***azo-***.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a cognate: *stick* (as in *stick out* or *stick a needle in someone*).

The German and Dutch words (as well as Scandinavian equivalents like Danish *kvælstof* and Swedish *kväve*) are derived from verbs meaning ‘smother, stifle, strangle’, since nitrogen cannot sustain fire, but ‘smothers’ it. So a literal calque would be ‘smother element’.

The German and Dutch verbs are cognates; I'll just focus on the German one here. The verb in German is *ersticken*, which is an [*er-* extension](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/er-#German) to the base verb *stecken* (not as one might expect *sticken*, which is a different, though related, verb). *Stecken* means ‘stick’ in various different senses related to putting something in some place or into a hole (sticking a nail in a wall, etc.) or fastening something (making it stick); it is in origin the causative of *stechen*, which means ‘be sharp, sting, prick’. So if a nurse injects a needle into your arm, the needle *sticht* you, the nurse *sticht* you, and the nurse *steckt* the needle into your arm.

Etymologically, all these verbs are of course related, in quite complex ways. *Stecken* in Modern German represents a merger in Middle High German of two verbs that were in Old High German distinct (though very similar), which [Duden quotes](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stecken#block-duden-tiles-5) as *stecchen* ‘stick/adhere to, fasten to’ and *stecchēn* ‘stick into, pierce’. Of these, the latter is the original causative (Old High German verbs in *-ēn* generally come from Proto-Germanic **-janą*, which was the standard causative ending in the infinitive). Of course, it’s not really a true causative at all (a true causative of ‘be sharp’ would be ‘make sharp’ or ‘sharpen’), but the causative in Germanic was quite a broad concept, and there are many morphological causatives that aren’t semantical causatives.

I haven’t seen any conclusive explanations on the development from sticking/pricking/sharpness to strangling or suffocating. In fact the [DWDS etymology](http://www.dwds.de/wb/ersticken#et-1) for the verb *ersticken* pronounces itself uncertain:

> Der semantische Zusammenhang ist undurchsichtig. Ist für *ersticken* von ‘durch mehrere Stiche töten’ (vgl. mhd. *si lāgen ersticket und verdorben*) mit nachfolgender Bedeutungsentwicklung zu ‘(an Luftmangel) sterben, (durch Entziehen der Luft) töten’ (wie ¹DWB 10, 2, 2, 2742 vermutet) auszugehen? Oder führt ‘hineinstecken, stopfen’ zu der Vorstellung ‘durch (Voll)stopfen den Hauch, den Atem benehmen’ (vgl. mhd. *ersticken und erworgen begunde er an dem beine*), also ‘mit dem Atem steckenbleiben und den Geist aufgeben’ mit nachfolgender (im Frühnhd. entwickelter) trans. Verwendung?<sup>1</sup>

My own personal guess would be that it could be connected to the sharp, stinging sensation you experience when you don’t have access to enough oxygen to satisfy your system: when exercising, when out of breath, when diving (without aqualungs) and drowning, at high altitudes, and importantly also when undergoing asphyxiation. In German, this sensation is called *Seiten**stechen***, an exact equivalent to English *side stitch* (‘stitch’ being also in English closely related to the noun ‘stick’—Scandinavian languages have equivalent expressions as well), so on some level there is a common Germanic connection between stinging/pricking/being sharp and the results of not being able to breathe.

So although English hasn’t developed a verb based on ‘stick’ that means ‘suffocate, etc.’, the most exact *etymological* cognate of the Dutch/German words is *stick*, and a purely formal cognate equivalent to *Stickstoff* is ‘stick stuff’. I wouldn’t recommend that you start referring to nitrogen as ‘stick stuff’, though.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I’m not the world’s best translator of German, but something like: “The semantic connection is unclear. Are we to assume that *ersticken* [suffocate] is from ‘killing through multiple stabs’ (cf. MHG *si lāgen ersticket und verdorben* ‘they lay stabbed and rotten/ruined’), with subsequent semantic shift to ‘die (from lack of air), kill (through deprivation of air)’ (as ¹DWB 10, 2, 2, 2742 assumes)? Or did ‘stick, plug into’ lead to the notion of ‘taking away someone’s breath through ‘plugging up’ their windpipe’ (cf. MHG *ersticken und erworgen begunde er an dem beine*), thus ‘getting your breath stuck and giving up the ghost’ with subsequent (and in Early Modern German extended) transitive usage?”</sup>

Comment: One might mention that *stechen* and *stecken* do have have the same *mittelhochdeutsche Wurzel.* Of course, that's about a few hundred years before nitrogen as singular was discovered and dubbed *Stickstoff.*

Comment: @Helmar I actually meant to include that—must have gotten sidetracked in one of the many sentences in this answer that kind of ran away from me. Posting answers from your phone is rarely a good idea. Will edit in.

Comment: Great addition, would up vote again if I could :)

Comment: Great in-depth answer! I didn't think it'd be that obvious since I couldn't explain the meaning of English "stick" in comparison with other cognates, and I couldn't find any useful etymologies of Stick and stik.

Comment: As an aside, it would also seem plausible to me that the semantic relation for "stick" and "smother" would be the sense that smothering happens when something obstructs the breathing and is not removed; it essentially "sticks" to the face / in the throat until suffocation begins to occur.